# How to change the first number in brackets with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file that looks like this:

```
SizeMinMax: [ 8, 14 ]
SizeMinMax: [ 4, 8 ]
SizeMinMax: [ 6, 10 ]
```

and so on.

I need to set the first number in the brackets to 0 for all entries, so that it looks like this:

```
SizeMinMax: [ 0, 14 ]
SizeMinMax: [ 0, 8 ]
SizeMinMax: [ 0, 10 ]
```

I'm really bad with regular expressions, can someone teach me what kind of expression i need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to replace digits just after the openning bracket only when there is `SizeMinMax:` before.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `SizeMinMax: \[\h*\K\d+`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
SizeMinMax: \[  # literally
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\d+             # 1 or more digits
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can search for digits, immediately followed by a comma:

(explanation below the image)

[image]

In the Replace popup, ensure to toggle:

1. Wrap around
2. Regular expression

In the `Find what` input, use: `\d+(,)`

In the `Replace with` input, use: `0\1`

The `Find what` regex means:

```
\d  - a digit
+   - any other trailing digits (with the \d, matches 1 or more consecutive digits)
(,) - capture the comma to use with replace.
```

The `Replace with` regex means:

```
0  - a literal zero
\1 - this is replaced with the comma from the find.
```

Comment: T great answer. One of the issues I get with using regular expressions is that different searches and replaces in different contexts (e.g when using different apps, notepad, Visual Studio etc) seem to need slightly different regular expression syntax. Is the notepad syntax some type of 'standard' syntax or a particular 'flavour'?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow ... you know, I wasn't sure, had to check. According to their documentation, it claims: `uses the Boost regular expression engine`. (when the regular expression option is toggled)  Here's [a link](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) to that info. And Boost is PCRE compatible (with minor deviations) according to that link as well.

Comment: 20 years in software and I just found out that the regex standard is IEEE POSIX, and that the lowest level of standard compliance is BRE (Basic Regular Expressions). Where that leaves Perl Compatible Regular Expressions I'm not sure?